# how to open partition with CreateFile API?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to get handle from drive `C:/`.I can get handle from disk by:

```
HANDLE hd = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

how to access partition of disk?

when use this code:

```
HANDLE hd = CreateFile("\\.\C", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

and use GetLastError() error code is 123.

> ERROR_INVALID_NAME
>
> 123 (0x7B)
>
> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

from Microsoft doc:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX2AC.jpg)

but not work!

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name you should be using to open a volume is `C:` and make sure the back slashes are escaped appropriately.

```
HANDLE hd = CreateFile("\\\\.\\C:", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

Note that you will probably get error 5 (Access denied), unless the exe is being run with administrator privileges.

Comment: @mohammadmadani oops, took me a minute to realise the backslashes weren't escaped properly. Answer updated.

Comment: This is covered in the [`CreateFile()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx).

Comment: how to open it for write? I use the above code with GENERIC_WRITE, but get error code 32 : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process